# SQL: trying to find rows that contain the char '1'

Tags: sql, char, substring, contains

I have an ACCESS table (called OS) with 3 columns - OS_NAME , VERSION (both text), PRICE (number) 
I am trying to find all the names of all OS's with the char '1' in the version (e.g. version v11), but when I use this query:
 `SELECT OS_NAME FROM OS WHERE VERSION LIKE '%1%'` 
Im not getting any reasult, just a blank table.
I tried writing  `SELECT OS_NAME FROM OS WHERE VERSION LIKE 'v11'` 
 and all was OK and I got the right row...
So, is there a problem with my '%'? 
I thought they should give me all string containing '1'

Comment: It should. post sample data that your query doesn't work on.

Comment: OK, I was just told that I need to replace '%' with '*' and it worked. I guess it has something to do with ACCESS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ACCESS [you should](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php) use `*` instead of `%` :

```
 SELECT OS_NAME FROM OS WHERE VERSION LIKE '*1*'
```